# Configuring WoL on Desktop Computer

Tags: wake-on-lan

I would like to configure wake on lan, on my desktop, but I have no idea where to start. My motherboard is a Asus Prime z270m-plus. I have a RPI set up that I am able to SSH into to send the packet.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: ASUS has a guide, it might be a bit different on each model, but it shall be similar https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/114359/

Answer (score 0):

WoL is dependent on two things:

- First check your BIOS if your motherboard have that option or not.
- Your Ethernet or wireless card must also support this functionality.
  Control Panel> Device Manger > your network card > properties > check for WOL option there.

**If you want to send the command from your raspberry! open terminal**

```
# wakeonlan MAC-Address-Here
```

**NOTE:**
If you want to send the WOL from outside the network you should have static IP address + Open port in your router to access your computer from outside.